# Git push : Permission denied to user, could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, permissions, push

I'm trying to use the command

```
git push origin branch
```

to push on gitHub (public repository)

I have the  following error :

> ERROR: Permission to emilyreese/connaissance.git denied to
>   vulkanosaure fatal: Could not read from remote repository

I'm using git for windows (i tried both 64 bits and 32 bits version)

**What i already did :**

- generate a ssh key using : `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C
  "my_email@example.com"`
- add this ssh key to the ssh-agent : `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
- add the key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub into my GitHub account
- use the command `ssh-add -l -E md5` to obtain the fingerprint of my key, and compare it to what i see on my GitHub account
- change the file my_repository/.git/config and replace url = https://github.com/path_to_repo.git by
  git@github.com:path_to_repo.git to try HTTPS and SSH methods

Any help will be much appreciated !

Comment: It looks like you are trying to push to a github repository owned by another user.  Unless that person has explicitly granted you commit access, that's not going to work.

Comment: ok, i misunderstood how it works. I forked the project, pushed to my fork, and this works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case what you can do is

1. Fork this project to your account;
2. Make your commits;
3. Push to your repository;
4. Submit a merge request to the original project;

This way you can continue your work on your forked repository or contribute to the original project (always good to return something good to the community).

Comment: Thanks, that's what i found out later by discussing with a friend. I misunderstood the concept of merge request.